# how to access elements within #document / sub document in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Unable to access elements within #document after running createLogin()

Things I've tried so far

1: document.getElementtById("signIn-container"); 
2: document.getElementById("object #document div.signIn-container");
3: document.getElementById("#document.signIn-container");
4: document.querySelectorAll("signIn-container"); returns empty array

```js
function createLogin(){
  var x = document.getElementById("route-view");
  x.innerHTML= '<object type="text/html" data="./resources/views/logIn.html" ></object>';
};
```

```html
 <html>
 <head>...</head>
 <body>
     <header>
     
            </header>
            
 <div id="top-app-name-container">...</div>
 <div id="nav">...</div>
 <!-- routing view --> == $0
   <object type="text/html" data="./resources/views/login.html">
   #document
   <html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
    <div id="signIn-container">
     <div class="username">..</div>
     <div class="password">..</div>
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
     </object>
```

Comment: You need to use `document.querySelector(...)` or `querySelectorAll` (prepend IDs with #, classes with .) as `getElementById` expects a single ID (without #), not a CSS selector

Comment: Thanks for clarification however that still didn't work for me i think ill have to do some more digging tomorrow ill update my findings